# How to convert a public key from string type to PEM?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, x509certificate, signature, public-key

I need to send a message from sender to receiver, and the message content is signed data and public key and other things. Note that I use the certificate x509 (the public key is from the certificate).

On the receiver side, I must verify the signature of the data (whether it is valid or not). So, I use the public key of the sender for verification.

But the problem is the public key is ib string format, so I tried to convert it. But unfortunately, I did't find any solution.

This is the message that will be sent:

```
data['message'] = data
data['_signature'] = self.sign_data(data)   
data['_public_key'] = str ( self.certificate.public_key())
```

Comment: You should be sending the whole certificate, not just the public key. The receiver can get the public key from the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert the public key (`certificate.public_key()`) into string by using `str`, because this method will return a key object.

If you need to encode the public key as a PEM string, then you have to do it correctly, by serialization into PEM:

```
public_pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)
```

Then from other side, you could load the PEM key and use it:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

public_key2 = serialization.load_pem_public_key(public_pem, default_backend())
```

Comment: "... because this method will return key object": no it won't, it will return a possibly lossy conversion of the key bytes to a string,

Answer (score -4):

I write the file locally then call it

```
my_string = "certificate in pem/key"
with open("new_file_written.pem", "w") as f:
    f.write(my_string)
```

```
curl bla bla new_file_written.pem
```

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: What is "bla bla"?